# Stitching binary image in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

For text detection, I split the entire image for better results (all those images with the same dimensions having ****overlapping****) and generate its **mask(Binary image)** and merge those split images into one full image(with the dimension of the original image).

image:
[Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moD2U.jpg)
[split images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7cc0.png) [masked binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDQTl.png)

now I used to merge all these images, but the overlapped image where the text not detected removes the white patch in the image [full merged mask image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBSoQ.png).

In order to overcome this issue I came to know about the stitching image in OpenCV, hence I used this link for stitching imagehttps://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/17/image-stitching-with-opencv-and-python/#pyi-pyimagesearch-plus-pricing-modal, but this code doesn't work for a binary image. Is it possible to stitch binary image with overlapping in OpenCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stitching in OpenCV python is only for panorama images(camera images) where it finds and matches the features in the image as you refer to this link:https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d46/group__stitching.html

if you want to get merge those image you can use it simply with `PIL` in python:https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste

merge those image with :`image.paste(im, (x, y),mask=im)` Where the mask is 255, the given image is copied as is. Where the mask is 0, the current value is preserved.